# Filter genes >10 reads in at least 2 replicates

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Hello I need to filter genes from this data >10 reads in at least 2 replicates.

```
PancreasLungDesign
                         Individual sex   age RNA.quality..max10.    organ   tissue
GTEX-1KXAM-0226-SM-EV7AP GTEX-1KXAM   1 60-69                 7.2 Pancreas Pancreas
GTEX-18A67-1726-SM-7KFT9 GTEX-18A67   1 50-59                 7.5 Pancreas Pancreas
GTEX-14BMU-0726-SM-73KXS GTEX-14BMU   2 20-29                 7.2 Pancreas Pancreas
GTEX-13PVR-0726-SM-5S2PX GTEX-13PVR   2 60-69                 7.3 Pancreas Pancreas
GTEX-1211K-1126-SM-5EGGB GTEX-1211K   2 60-69                 7.3 Pancreas Pancreas
GTEX-11TT1-0326-SM-5LUAY GTEX-11TT1   1 20-29                 7.7 Pancreas Pancreas
GTEX-1KXAM-0426-SM-DHXKG GTEX-1KXAM   1 60-69                 9.1     Lung     Lung
GTEX-18A67-1126-SM-7KFSB GTEX-18A67   1 50-59                 8.5     Lung     Lung
GTEX-14BMU-0526-SM-73KW4 GTEX-14BMU   2 20-29                 9.2     Lung     Lung
GTEX-1211K-0826-SM-5FQUP GTEX-1211K   2 60-69                 8.2     Lung     Lung
GTEX-11TT1-1626-SM-5EQL7 GTEX-11TT1   1 20-29                 8.9     Lung     Lung
GTEX-ZYFG-0226-SM-5GIDT   GTEX-ZYFG   2 60-69                 8.7     Lung     Lung
```

```
    counts
                GTEX-Y5V6-0526-SM-4VBRV GTEX-1KXAM-1726-SM-D3LAE GTEX-18A67-0826-SM-7KFTI GTEX-14BMU-0226-SM-5S2QA

ENSG00000243485                       0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000237613                       1                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000186092                       2                        2                        2                        0
ENSG00000238009                       1                        0                        0                       12
ENSG00000222623                       0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000241599                       0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000236601                       0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000235146                       0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000223181                       0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000237491                     214                      205                      164                      108
ENSG00000177757                      20                       40                       57                       42
ENSG00000225880                     214                      114                      146                      149
ENSG00000230368                       2                        4                        2                        0
ENSG00000272438                       5                        2                       11                        2
ENSG00000230699                      27                       37                       25                       23
ENSG00000241180                       0                        0                        0                        0
                GTEX-13PVR-0626-SM-5S2RC GTEX-1211K-0726-SM-5FQUW GTEX-1KXAM-0926-SM-CXZKA GTEX-18A67-2626-SM-718AD
ENSG00000243485                        0                        0                        2                        7
ENSG00000237613                        0                        0                        1                        3
ENSG00000186092                        0                        0                        2                        7
ENSG00000238009                        0                        2                        2                        2
ENSG00000222623                        0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000241599                        0                        0                        0                        1
ENSG00000236601                        1                        1                        0                        5
ENSG00000235146                        0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000223181                        0                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000237491                      100                      174                       99                      116
ENSG00000177757                       60                       73                       27                       36
ENSG00000225880                      126                      221                      101                       97
ENSG00000230368                        0                       12                        6                        6
ENSG00000272438                        4                        0                        3                        5
ENSG00000230699                       32                       10                       20                       24
ENSG00000241180                        0                        0                        0                        0
```

I tried with these lines of code:

```
Expressedgenes=counts>10

NumExpressedgenes=apply(Expressedgenes,1,sum)

FilteredCounts=counts[NumExpressedgenes>0,]
```

But in this way it means that I filter genes for >10 reads but for only 1 replicate right? how can I filter for at least 2?

```
GTEX-Y5V6-0526-SM-4VBRV GTEX-1KXAM-1726-SM-D3LAE GTEX-18A67-0826-SM-7KFTI GTEX-14BMU-0226-SM-5S2QA
```

ENSG00000243485                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000237613                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000186092                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000238009                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                     TRUE
ENSG00000222623                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000241599                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000236601                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000235146                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000223181                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000237491                    TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE
ENSG00000177757                    TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE
ENSG00000225880                    TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE
ENSG00000230368                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE
ENSG00000272438                   FALSE                    FALSE                     TRUE                    FALSE
ENSG00000230699                    TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE                     TRUE
ENSG00000241180                   FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE                    FALSE

Comment: Your `counts > 10` returns a logical matrix.  when you say genes > 10, is it the column names of 'counts' data.  Not clear about the replicate part

Comment: Also, the Individual column in the first data seems to show two words i.e. `GTEX-1KXAM-0226-SM-EV7AP GTEX-1KXAM` (separated by space).  So are you trying to match the first word with the column name from 'counts'.  If you can update your post with the expected output from this, it would be helpful

Comment: Replicates are columns in counts, there are 60 columns so 60 replicates, and for replicates  it can be considered like the repetition of the experiment in order to find some variations in measurements

Comment: If you can update your post with expected output, it would be more clear as I am not sure what your expected output is

Comment: in Design there are 60 rows, that are the 60 replicates, but I think that I could omit it since the filter should be done only on counts

Comment: So the reads that i need to keep are the TRUE returned by the 1st line of code :Expressedgenes=counts>10 but they need to be true in at least 2 columns (replicates)

Comment: Can you please edit your post with the expected output dataset so that it becomes clear (for the example input you have)

Comment: I am sorry I was trying but Im not able to show the code correctly, If someone could fix it, there there's each read which is true or false in each replicate(column) so i should select all the rows that have a TRUE in at least 2 columns.

Comment: Try the solution I posted (based on your description of at least 2 columns)

Answer (score 0):

If we need at least two columns to be TRUE, create the logical vector with `rowSums`

```
i1 <- rowSums(counts>10, na.rm = TRUE) > 1
counts[i1,]
```

Comment: ExpressedPancr2=rowSums(PancrCounts>10, na.rm = TRUE) > 1
NumExpressedgenespancr2=sapply(ExpressedPancr2,1,sum,)  when i try to run it in this way i get the error: Error in apply(ExpressedPancr2, 1, sum) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length             did i do anything wrong?

Comment: I think that the problem is that in this way let me keep only the rows without the columns

Comment: ok I understood, I was just missing the other line to set the columns, I am sorry everything is fine thank you

Comment: `ExpressedPancr2` is already a vector of sums converted to logical vector.  You don't `apply` (`sapply` code is wrong too)